# Spring-boot RESTful services not being used when implementing AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

I set this all up by hand and when the application starts spring-boot displays the index.html page with has a AngularJS `<div ng-view></div>` my configuration files do work in my AngularJS project but now I am trying to get information back from my restful services and it appears they are no longer being called. Pretty much once it is passed to index.html, angular takes control.

indexController.java

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("Looking in the index controller.........");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

FormRestController.java

```
@RestController
public class FormRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    //-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {

        System.out.println("listAllUsers() is being called inside RestController............");

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

users.config.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider.when('/users', {
            templateUrl: 'app/scripts/Customers/users.html',
            controller: 'UsersController'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

    }]);
```

usersService.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('usersService',['$http', '$q', function($http,$q){

return {

    fetchAllUsers: function(){
        console.log("inside fetchAllUsers");
        return $http.get('/getUsers')
            .then(
                function(response){
                    return response;
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error("Error while fetching customers"+errResponse);
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

}]);

users.controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('UsersController', ['$scope', 'usersService', function($scope,    
usersService){

this.user = {id:null, username:'', address:'',email:''};
this.users = [];

var self = this;

this.fetchAllUsers = function(){
    var usersSelf = self;

    usersService.fetchAllUsers()
        .then(
            function(d){
                usersSelf.users = d
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error("Error while catching something"+errResponse);
            }
        );
}
}]);
```

users.html

```
<div ng-controller="UsersController as ctrl">

      <table class="table table-hover" ng-init="ctrl.fetchAllUsers()">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID.</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th width="20%"></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.users">
              <td>{{u.id}}</td>
              <td>{{u.username}}</td>
              <td>{{u.address}}</td>
              <td>{{u.email}}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

home.html  (This is the root page)

```
<div>
    <h2>You have landed on the home page!!!</h2>

    <a ng-href="#/users">Click here to go to the next page...</a>

</div>
```

output

[image]

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is inside promise callback. Store reference to `this` and use that reference

Answer (score 0):

The your problem hear is that `this` isn't the correct pointer for popolate the data in your ui. this is becouse javascript works differentry respect to java and other programming language.

whit this small changes the your code should works.

```
controller( "" , ... 

 this.user = {};
        this.users = [];
        var self = this;

        this.fetchAllUsers = function(){
            var uresSelf = self;

            usersService.fetchAllUsers()
                .then(
                function(d){
                    uresSelf.users = d.data
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error("Error while catching something");
                }
            );
        }
```

the key point is how javascript, respect to the fact if you use "use strict" or no, when use this in function works ina partucular way remember tha function are objects in javascript even if you write a function js engine tract a function as an object and the this reference of the main function(the mani object) was different respect to the this of a inner function(onother object).

The tipical workaround hear was that:
Becouse you can't use `this` of the outer function in the inner function you create a reference in this way you througth the reference previously built can refer to the outer this in the inner funciotn.

```
function outerFunction(){

 var outerThis = this;

  function innerFunction(){
     console.log("this the this of the outer function" + outerThis );
     console.log("this the this of the inner function" + this);  
 }();

}
```

resuming  I post all the code of the my poc for validate what I written:

the context configuration was:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
@RestController
class FormRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    //-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {

        System.out.println("listAllUsers() is being called inside RestController............");

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
class User{

    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String address;
    private String email;
}

@Service
class UserService {

    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        users.add(User.builder().id(1).username("valerio").address("via sessa aurunca").email("v.vòg.v").build());
        users.add(User.builder().id(2).username("valerio1").address("via sessa aurunca").email("v.vòg.v").build());
        users.add(User.builder().id(3).username("valerio2").address("via sessa aurunca").email("v.vòg.v").build());
        users.add(User.builder().id(4).username("valerio3").address("via sessa aurunca").email("v.vòg.v").build());
        users.add(User.builder().id(5).username("valerio4").address("via sessa aurunca").email("v.vòg.v").build());

        return users;
    }
}
```

the htmo file was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="UsersController as ctrl">

    <table class="table table-hover" ng-init="ctrl.fetchAllUsers()">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th width="20%"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.users">
            <td>{{u.id}}</td>
            <td>{{u.username}}</td>
            <td>{{u.address}}</td>
            <td>{{u.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the js file was:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .factory('usersService',['$http', '$q', function($http,$q){
        return {


            fetchAllUsers: function(){
                return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/users')
                    .then(
                    function(response){
                        return response;
                    },
                    function(errResponse){
                        console.error("Error while fetching customers");
                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                    }
                );
            }
        }

    }]).controller('UsersController', function($scope, usersService){

        this.user = {};
        this.users = [];
        var self = this;

        this.fetchAllUsers = function(){
            var uresSelf = self;

            usersService.fetchAllUsers()
                .then(
                function(d){
                    uresSelf.users = d.data
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error("Error while catching something");
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

I hope that i was clear in my answare and that can help you.

Comment: I did what you said and it is still now working. Once I see it all working I know it will click. This is my first time hooking it all up by hand. *note* d.data is not a unresolved variable. 

It also looks like "self" is "this" in your example. You are just passing "this" around. I understand a little what you are referring to though. The project is on GIT if you wanted to look at it. https://github.com/drewjocham/SpringCRUD.git but I am pretty sure you will have to (npm install) on its path if you do pull it

Comment: ok I forked your project and try to fix in the original code the problem

Comment: I'm sorry but I had many problem to build the your project but I had implemetns a poc and works for my sample, acctually I forgotten to add the ng-init in my answare but I post this in another answare.

Comment: if can helps I used Angular in my github, if you want can see the my account https://github.com/mrFlick72 I can suggest to see phoneboock

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Yes this project does require some configuration on your IDE. You have to do npm install and make sure bower_components is under webapp/app/bower_components.

I looked at your project and it seems to be Spring-MVC and I am using spring-boot.

Comment: I resuming the 3 answare in one

Comment: I made some changes. If you pull the project again then in your terminal put in `npm install` then a folder app will be created. Inside newly created app folder move bower_components to webapp/app. The program will be up and running.  github.com/drewjocham/SpringCRUD.git

Comment: I pulled a two bug-fix now you can see the table popolated

Comment: I can suggest to think about a lot of things like the naming conventions for java package, user Controller and not RestController for the view layer RestController for end-point rest layer an so on

Comment: I do not see anything different in your above code. Yes I do agree I was sloppy with my naming convention. This was a project I did for simple understanding and did not plan on posting it online.

Comment: is very strange becouse i see on your account the my pull request pending